# You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only -

Tags: python, twitter, jupyter-notebook

```py
import tweepy
import json
import pandas as pd

API_KEY = ''
API_SECRET = ' '
access_token = ''
access_token_seceret =''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

This code right here keeps giving me the error below, can anyone help me figure out how to fix the issue? I'm new to coding.

```py
facebooktweets = api.user_timeline("Meta")
```

```
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     TweepError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-8-96959e05857f> in <module>()
      ----> 1 facebooktweets = api.user_timeline("Meta")

      1 frames
      /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py in execute(self)
      232                     raise RateLimitError(error_msg, resp)
      233                 else:
  --> 234                     raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
      235 
      236             # Parse the response payload

     TweepError: [{'message': 'You currently have Essential access which includes access 
     to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need 
     to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: 
     https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter- 
     api#v2-access-leve', 'code': 453}]
```

Comment: The error message tells you *exactly what to do* - `apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal`. The alternative would be to use the Twitter API v2 version of the `user_timeline` function, which is [`get_users_tweets`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_users_tweets)

Answer (score 3):

It calls the v1.1 API. But the v1.1 API is not available in Essential access. Use the v2 API only: [tweepy.Client — Twitter API v2 Reference — tweepy](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html)

Comment: How do you get access to v1.1? I had access when I first started building my application and then suddenly it disappeared. Now it says I only have access to v2 endpoints, but I can't use any v2 endpoints because in my developer portal it literally says I only have access to v1.1, yet I still get this message.

Comment: @MartinErlic See [here](https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/1621026986784337922). Both not accessible for free anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is no free access no more. Prob a good thing to stop the bots.

See the update on twitter [here](https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/1621026986784337922)